# function with while loop python with two different result

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I want to code a function and get expected results like this (when i input number = 10):

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

And when i input number = -10 :

```
-10
-9
-8
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
```

This is my code. Only works when number = 10. No result when im trying to input a = -10:

```
def function_while(number):
i=0
while i<number:     
    if True:
        print(number-i)
    else:
        print(number+1)
    i+=1
function_while(number)
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a for-loop over a while loop since you know the number of iterations needed:

```
def f(n):
    sign = -1 if n < 0 else 1
    for i in reversed(range(1, abs(n)+1)):
        print(i*sign)
```

But, if you're set on the while loop:

```
def function_while(x):
    sign = -1 if x < 0 else 1
    number = abs(x)
    i=0
    while i<number:     
        print((number-i)*sign)
        i+=1
```

The trick is to use a variable, sign which is -1 if the input is negative, otherwise 1.

Answer (score 0):

Be pythonic, use a simple `range`:

```
def f(number):
    for i in range(number, 0, -1 if number>0 else 1):
        print(i)
```

Example:

```
f(5)
5
4
3
2
1

f(-5)
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(num):
    step = -1 if num > 0 else 1
    while num != 0:
        print(num)
        num += step
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.